# Captions without labels

Tags: subcaption

I am using `subcaption` but even if I copy paste code from the intenet, the result for me has no sublabels (a), (b) etc.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = simple}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}
    \centering\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
    \caption{This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption.}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide complete small document with your figure. Problem seems to be in its preamble. With my standard preamble for documents with sub figures I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: I edited the code to include it. `\documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}` the problem?

Comment: Try: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{This is a sub-caption.}\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{This is a sub-caption.}\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.3\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}   
\caption{This is a sub-caption.}\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}\end{document}`

Comment: Documentclass which you use, is not on CTAN, so can't test how it work with it. With standard article   I obtain your desired result.

Comment: @Zarko Yes that works. The caption labels work for `subfigures` instead of `subcaptions` using my document class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately document class, which you use, is not public available.

**Edit:**
SInce you meanwhile provide link to `jpconf` document class, I tested my solution with it. Unfortunately  this document class is not compatible with `caption` nor with `subcaption` package. As solution I sugest to use `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
\hfill% <---
\subfloat[This is a sub-caption.]{
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
\hfill% <---
\subfloat[This is a sub-caption. This is a sub-caption]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
\caption{Common caption}
 \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which gives gives the following result:

[image]

In comparison to your MWE I increase images width to 0.3\linewidth and than remove `\centering` command. Between `subfloats` I insert `\hfill` which push `subfloats` apart.

Comment: I tried the same but with my document class and it doesn't seem to work. It is available from this link http://cms.iopscience.iop.org/alfresco/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/a83f1ab6-cd8f-11e0-be51-5d01ae4695ed/LaTeXTemplates.zip

Comment: @user7867665, see edited answer. Does it now solve your problem )on acceptable way)?

Comment: I'll switch to `subfig`. I don't know why it doesn't support `subcaption`

Comment: there's an extra `\end{figure}` but thanks!